# Mannual Weight Updates for (bi-directional) RNN in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

`static_bidirectional_rnn` take optional `initial_state_fw`, `initial_state_bw` parameters for initilization and return `output_state_fw`, `output_state_bw`. Is it possible to use these states to make mannual weight changes in rnn?

- start with `zero_state` for `initial_state_fw`, `initial_state_bw`
- get value `output_state_fw`, `output_state_bw`
- change weights of `hidden_state(h)` and  `bias(c)` of both output state
- create `initial_states` using updated weights and continue training